# Jupyter kernel with TensorFlow GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

Having trouble getting the GPU recognized as a physical device for my Jupyter Notebook kernel.

From the command-line I have an env. setup like this, which looks okay:

```
(base) > conda activate tf-gpu
(tf-gpu) > python
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> tf.config.list_physical_devices()
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:CPU:0', device_type='CPU'), 
PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]
```

I have changed kernel to "tf-gpu" in Jupyter, but the GPU is not recognized:
[image: Jupyter screenshot]

Any advice?

Comment: Look at the console log of jupyter and it should have the tensorflow messages on why it is not finding your GPU.

Comment: You are right:

tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudnn64_8.dll'; dlerror: cudnn64_8.dll not found

tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1850] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
Skipping registering GPU devices...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message in the Jupyter console log was:

> tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could
> not load dynamic library 'cudnn64_8.dll'; dlerror: cudnn64_8.dll not
> found
>
> tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1850] Cannot dlopen
> some GPU libraries.
>
> Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed
> properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at
> tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required
> libraries for your platform. Skipping registering GPU devices

I ended up copying `cudnn64_8.dll` from `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA\CUDNN\v8.3\bin` to `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.6\bin` and restarted Jupyter.

I now have this:
[image]

Thanks to [Dr. Snoopy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71748635/jupyter-kernel-with-tensorflow-gpu?noredirect=1#comment126800208_71748635) for the pointer!